# CSharpCodeProvider throwing "'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." on the same file it's generating

Tags: c#, file, exception, csharpcodeprovider

...and it's not because the file was there to begin with. I can prove it.

The background is this: We have a desktop application which generate WORD/PDF documents. The document consist of Building blocks - small classes that produces a certain layout, and which can be plugged into different data sources, and which is dynamically combined together to build up the document. I don't think this is relevant, but for the sake of completeness, I'm using ASPOSE to generate the documents.

There was also another requirement: We need to be able to change the C# code of the building blocks and make it available on production without having to do a release. The solution we opted for was to save the code for the various building blocks in the Database, and to precompile them during the start-up of the application: When the Application starts, it gets the code from the database, and compile them into separate assemblies which it then dumps into the application's temp folder. In order to prevent the "file is being used by another process" error, I added a datetime stamp to the name of each assembly - up to the millisecond. I keep track of the assembly version by storing the datetime stamp in a static variable. This way, if the user refresh the application, or open another instance, it safely generates a new set of dll's with unique names, which - in theory - ensures that I will never get the "File used by another process" exception. When all instances of the application is closed, the temp folder is wiped. (And we haven't had problems with that) 99.9% of the time, this solution works perfectly. It is quick and efficient, and keeps the dll's up to date when we make changes. BUT!

Our error handling code sends emails to a server, and I've been getting the "File being used by another process" error! In my error handling code, I've done the following: When the exception is thrown, I get a list of all the Dll's that already exists in the folder. I also have a list of all the dll's that was generated during that iteration. All this information is then included in the error message. This only added to the confusion: In all cases, the error occurs on the last file that was added (not updated) to the folder, with no hint that there could've been a duplicate file name. Also, the error never occurs on the same file. Sometimes it is on the very first file being generated, other times it happens only after most of the files have already been created. The error also happens so infrequently, that I have been unable to replicate it. Asking the user for more information will be of little value, because they only notice a problem if they try to generate a report, and that can be hours after they opened the application. Besides, this process occurs before the user can actually do anything in the application anyway.

The error message I receive is:

> Message: System.Exception: An error occured while compiling E_Text --->
>   System.Exception: 8 Errors:
>   Line: 4 - The using directive for 'System' appeared previously in this namespace
>   Line: 5 - The using directive for 'System.Collections.Generic' appeared previously in this namespace
>   Line: 188 - 'C####l.Framework.Reporting.ReportWriter.GeneratorCoreExtendedBase.AddContentWithTags(string, bool, C####l.Framework.Reporting.ReportWriter.FontTemplateTypes)' is obsolete: 'Rather use the ContentWithTagsParameters parameter, as this makes it easier to add more parameters later on.'
>   Line: 153 - The variable 'ex' is declared but never used
>   Line: 161 - The variable 'ex' is declared but never used
>   Line: 171 - The variable 'ex' is declared but never used
>   Line: 182 - The variable 'ex' is declared but never used
>   Line: 0 - Could not write to output file 'c:\Users\a#####e\Documents\T###s\Temp\E_Text_201402141156300351.dll' -- 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. '
>
> FILES ADDED TO THE TEMP FOLDER:
>
> added-C:\Users\a#####e\Documents\T###s\Temp\ExtendedGenerator_201402141156300351.dll
>   added-C:\Users\a#####e\Documents\T###s\Temp\E_Header_1_201402141156300351.dll
>   added-C:\Users\a#####e\Documents\T###s\Temp\S_StyleDefault_201402141156300351.dll
>   added-C:\Users\a#####e\Documents\T###s\Temp\E_Footer_1_201402141156300351.dll
>   added-C:\Users\a#####e\Documents\T###s\Temp\E_Area_Line_Chart_201402141156300351.dll
>   added-C:\Users\a#####e\Documents\T###s\Temp\H_ImageHeader_201402141156300351.dll
>   added-C:\Users\a#####e\Documents\T###s\Temp\S_DefaultEditableContent_201402141156300351.dll
>   added-C:\Users\a#####e\Documents\T###s\Temp\S_DefaultCoverLetter_201402141156300351.dll
>   added-C:\Users\a#####e\Documents\T###s\Temp\E_Client_Address_And_Salutation_201402141156300351.dll
>
> FILES CURRENTLY IN TEMP FOLDER:
>   C:\Users\a#####e\Documents\T###s\Temp\ExtendedGenerator_201402141156300351.dll
>   C:\Users\a#####e\Documents\T###s\Temp\E_Area_Line_Chart_201402141156300351.dll
>    C:\Users\a#####e\Documents\T###s\Temp\E_Client_Address_And_Salutation_201402141156300351.dll
>   C:\Users\a#####e\Documents\T###s\Temp\E_Footer_1_201402141156300351.dll
>   C:\Users\a#####e\Documents\T###s\Temp\E_Header_1_201402141156300351.dll
>   C:\Users\a#####e\Documents\T###s\Temp\E_Text_201402141156300351.dll
>   C:\Users\a#####e\Documents\T###s\Temp\H_ImageHeader_201402141156300351.dll
>   C:\Users\a#####e\Documents\T###s\Temp\S_DefaultCoverLetter_201402141156300351.dll
>   C:\Users\a#####e\Documents\T###s\Temp\S_DefaultEditableContent_201402141156300351.dll
>   C:\Users\a#####e\Documents\T###s\Temp\S_StyleDefault_201402141156300351.dll
>
> at C####l.Framework.Entity.ReportingCompiler.Compile(String assemblyName, String references, String code, List`1 addedFiles)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at C####l.Framework.Entity.ReportingCompiler.PrecompileElements(Object o, DbTransaction& transaction)
>   at C####l.Windows.Controls.BackgroundProcess.worker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) - An error occured while compiling E_Text
>   Stack Trace: at C####l.Framework.Entity.ReportingCompiler.PrecompileElements(Object o, DbTransaction& transaction)
>   at C####l.Windows.Controls.BackgroundProcess.worker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
>   Application: #####
>
> Version: #.#.##.####
>
> OSVersion: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
>
> Description: Failed to precompile reporting element

The code for the compiler is as follows:
When the application  is started, it calls the PrecompileElements method, and when the reports are generated, it calls the LoadAssembly method.
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
    using System.Text;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Reflection.Emit;
    using Microsoft.CSharp;
    using C####l.Framework.Configuration;
    using C####l.Framework.Mapping;
    using System.Data.Common;
    using C####l.Framework.Exceptions;

```
namespace C####l.Framework.Entity
{
    public class ReportingCompiler
    {
        #region Members
        private const string _assemblyVersionFile = "CurrentAssemblyVersion.txt";
        private List<Guid> _compiledGuids = new List<Guid>();
        private static string _assemblyVersion = "";
        private static bool _assembliesCompilationStarted = false;
        private static bool _isAssembliesCompiled = false;
        private static bool _assembliesCompilationFailed = false;
        private static string _assemblyLocation = "";
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        public static bool IsAssembliesCompiled
        {
            get { return _isAssembliesCompiled; }
            set { _isAssembliesCompiled = value; }
        }

        public static bool AssembliesCompilationFailed
        {
            get { return _assembliesCompilationFailed; }
            set { _assembliesCompilationFailed = value; }
        }

        public static bool AssembliesCompilationStarted
        {
            get { return _assembliesCompilationStarted; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// When set to an empty string, the value will default to the temporary folder.
        /// </summary>
        public static string AssemblyLocation
        {
            get 
            {
                if (_assemblyLocation.Length == 0)
                {
                    return GlobalSettings.TemporaryFolder;
                }
                else
                {
                    return _assemblyLocation;
                }
            }
            set { _assemblyLocation = value; }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods

        #region LoadAssembly
        public static Assembly LoadAssembly(string className)
        {
            Assembly assembly = null;
            if (!AssembliesCompilationStarted)
            {
                throw new FrameworkException("Cannot generate a report because the compilation of the reporting assemblies was never initiated.", false);
            }            
            if (AssembliesCompilationFailed)
            {
                throw new FrameworkException("Unable to generate report because the reporting assemblies failed to compile. Please restart the application, and report the issue if the problem persist.", false);
            }
            else if (!IsAssembliesCompiled)
            {
                throw new FrameworkException("Reporting assemblies are still compiling. Please wait a few seconds, and try again.", false);
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(GetFilePath(className));                    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    List<string> existingFiles = GetExistingFiles();
                    string files = "\r\n\r\nFILES CURRENTLY IN TEMP FOLDER:\r\n";
                    for (int i = 0; i < existingFiles.Count; i++)
                    {
                        files = files + existingFiles[i] + "\r\n";
                    }
                    Exception ex2 = new Exception(files, ex);
                    throw new Exception("An error occured while trying to retrieve assembly \"" + GetFilePath(className) + "\"", ex2);
                }
            }
            return assembly;
        }
        #endregion

        #region PrecompileElements
        public object PrecompileElements(object o, ref DbTransaction transaction)
        {
            _assembliesCompilationStarted = true;
            _assembliesCompilationFailed = false;
            _isAssembliesCompiled = false;
            try
            {
                GlobalSettings.CheckAsposeLicense();
                CreateVersionNumber();                
                ReportingExtendedGeneratorCoreCollection generators = (new ReportingExtendedGeneratorCoreMapper()).List();
                ReportingDynamicClassDefinitionCollection elements = (new ReportingDynamicClassDefinitionMapper()).List();
                string filePath = AssemblyLocation;
                List<string> addedFiles = new List<string>();

                for (int i = 0; i < generators.Count; i++)
                {
                    Compile(generators[i].CSharpClassName, generators[i].CSharpReferences, generators[i].CSharpCode, addedFiles);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < elements.Count; i++)
                {
                    _isAssembliesCompiled = false;
                    Compile(elements[i].CSharpClassName, elements[i].CSharpReferences, elements[i].CSharpCode, addedFiles);
                }
                _isAssembliesCompiled = true;
                return _isAssembliesCompiled;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _assembliesCompilationFailed = true;
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #endregion

        #region Private methods

        #region CreateVersionNumber
        private void CreateVersionNumber()
        {
            _assemblyVersion = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_ffff_");

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(AssemblyLocation);
            sb.Append(_assemblyVersionFile);
            File.WriteAllText(sb.ToString(), _assemblyVersion);
        }
        #endregion 

        #region GetExistingFiles
        private static List<string> GetExistingFiles()
        {
            List<string> currentFiles = null;
            try
            {
                currentFiles = new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles(AssemblyLocation, "*.dll"));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                currentFiles = new List<string>();
                currentFiles.Add("Could not obtain list of existing files for the following reason: " + ex.Message);
            }
            return currentFiles;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Compile
        private string Compile(string assemblyName, string references, string code, List<string> addedFiles)
        {
            try
            {
                IDictionary<string, string> providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                providerOptions["CompilerVersion"] = "v3.5";
                CodeDomProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(providerOptions);

                //            ICodeCompiler compiler = new CSharpCodeProvider(providerOptions).CreateCompiler();
                CompilerParameters compilerParameters = new CompilerParameters();
                string[] referencedAssemblies = references.Split(';');
                for (int i = 0; i < referencedAssemblies.Length; i++)
                {
                    compilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(referencedAssemblies[i]);
                }

                compilerParameters.GenerateInMemory = false; //true;
                compilerParameters.OutputAssembly = GetFilePath(assemblyName);

                CompilerResults compilerResults = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParameters, code);

                if (compilerResults.Errors.HasErrors)
                {
                    string lcErrorMsg = "";

                    // *** Create Error String
                    lcErrorMsg = compilerResults.Errors.Count.ToString() + " Errors:";
                    for (int x = 0; x < compilerResults.Errors.Count; x++)
                        lcErrorMsg = lcErrorMsg + "\r\nLine: " + compilerResults.Errors[x].Line.ToString() + " - " +
                            compilerResults.Errors[x].ErrorText;

                    lcErrorMsg = lcErrorMsg + "\r\n\r\nFILES ADDED TO THE TEMP FOLDER:\r\n";
                    for (int i = 0; i < addedFiles.Count; i++)
                    {
                        lcErrorMsg = lcErrorMsg + "added - " + addedFiles[i] + "\r\n";
                    }
                    List<string> existingFiles = GetExistingFiles();
                    lcErrorMsg = lcErrorMsg + "\r\n\r\nFILES CURRENTLY IN TEMP FOLDER:\r\n";
                    for (int i = 0; i < existingFiles.Count; i++)
                    {
                        lcErrorMsg = lcErrorMsg + existingFiles[i] + "\r\n";
                    }
                    throw new Exception(lcErrorMsg);
                    //MessageBox.Show(lcErrorMsg + "\r\n\r\n" + lcCode, "Compiler Demo", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    //return;
                }
                else
                {
                    addedFiles.Add(GetFilePath(assemblyName));
                }
                return compilerResults.PathToAssembly;//CompiledAssembly;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               throw new Exception("An error occured while compiling " + assemblyName, ex);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region GetFilePath
        private static string GetFilePath(string className)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(AssemblyLocation);            
            sb.Append(_assemblyVersion);
            sb.Append(className);
            sb.Append(".dll");
            return sb.ToString();
        }
        #endregion

        #endregion
    }
}
```

So far, my conclusion is that the exception is thrown from within the CSharpCodeProvider class, which pretty much limits what I can do about it. Almost as if it creates the file, and then - when it wants to write to it, it causes the error. But this is odd, because - as I understand it - dotNet uses this exact same class to compile projects as well, and I've never had this problem before.

If anybody have any insight into this what so ever, I will greatly appreciate your input.